# vue router.push gives an error 'Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is not a child of this node'

Tags: vue.js, dom, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I'm using Vue composition API, I'm trying to route the user to the 'notfound' page, but everytime I use `router.push` it gives me an error in the console `DOMException: Node.insertBefore: Child to insert before is not a child of this node`. also RouterLinks works fine.

to reproduce the error you can go to:
https://rest-countries-api.onrender.com/sdfsdf
(sdfsdf part is to generate the error)

to see the full code :
https://github.com/anas-cd/rest_api

pushing from : CountryView.vue

```html
<template>
.. (all templates .vue have a root node so this is not the problem)
</template>

<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
const router = useRouter();
router.push({ path: '/notfound' });
</script>
```

router index.js:

```js
    {
        path: '/notfound',
        name: 'NotFound',
        component: NotFound,
        meta: {
            scrollPos: {
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
            },
        },
    },
```

Comment: Pretty sure I saw that one as a pending bug in the Github issues of Vue. Can't find it as of right now sorry (on my phone).

Comment: @kissu, thanks for the info I'll look for it

Answer (score 1):

after updating all packages the error message was more informative.

I had an `await` inside a `ref()` and it caused problems,

```html
<script setup>
const data = ref(await apiCall()); // problem
</script>
```

```html
<script setup>
const data = ref(null);       // no problem
data.value = await apiCall(); //
</script>
```